# Python FastAPI Login Security - Should I Salt my hashes on both ends of my application? If so how do I do it?

Tags: python, security, hash, fastapi, bcrypt

I've recently been following the FastAPI Documentation on Security - OAuth2, Password Hashing, Bearer, and JWT. In attempt to setup my own Login/Token system. For the most part I understand the inner workings of what is going on under the hood.

My concern is when it comes to overall security and protection of peoples privacy. Most tutorials even FastAPI explains how to hash and store a password to your database. So I plan to Hash my users passwords when they are sent from the Front End in regards to User Creation and Forgot Password/Change Password.

Verifying in that sense it simple. The password is sent from the front end (In my case React) via form data. I use Bcrypt to "un-hash" / "compare" it and if it matches then the API will perform the process of assigning a token to the user.

I as a programmer/creator don't ever want to see users passwords in raw string format. So I want to hash passwords on the front-end also. I will use Bcrypt in my React application to Hash the raw string passwords.

My concern is though that a basic hash without any salt is practically worthless in the grand scheme of things. The salting process of a hash is a bit confusing to me. A salt's purpose to add unpredictability to a password hash. I'm under the impression that when Bcrypt generates salt the salt is never the same meaning the hashed version of the password is never the same. So if I apply salt to either side of my application (Front End React / Back End FastAPI) doesn't this mean I'll never be able to actually compare them?

Or does Bcrypt know how to compare salt + hashed strings? Or is the whole point of the hashing process to simply obscure the password from physical via and in all reality I shouldn't be salting my hashes?

Seriously appreciate anyone who can help me better understand this. I'm really working toward trying to be as secure as I can with my project.

I've read over several other post on this matter, but there seems to be more focus on if you should hash or not on back ends. In all reality I think at minimum a basic hash should be applied to both ends no matter what. I do not plan to ever store or see raw string passwords in my application.

Comment: There's no point in hashing on the front-end, it doesn't add any security because an interceptor can simply capture that hashed password and reuse it. Your question is more appropriate for [security.se] and has probably been asked before.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66475/for-an-https-web-application-is-it-worthwhile-to-encrypt-the-password-before-po

Comment: I see -- based on what you've provided the reality is that on the front-end the process is always visible in regards to a man in the middle attack. I managed to actually find https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right this. Stating that it's common to salt on the front-end using a persons email/username since the majority of your hashing security occurs on the backend. I will do this and focus more tightly on my backend systems toward security and privacy. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: The basic point is that hashing is not intended to protect against MITM, encryption is used for that. Hashing protects against cracking the plaintext passwords if you get a copy of the password database, and salting makes that even harder.

Comment: I appreciate your responses. I'm reading more into salting and even peppering currently and my knowledge gap here might be more derived from my lack of understanding of the process. I'm under the impression that a user could just use the salt to unhash the password. But what I am gathering is that it's more the salt is there to add complexity/time to the dehashing process. A person with a hash and a salt would still need to spend time on that process based on the complexity of the salt. This is to really buy you time to change passwords in the event of a hack.

Comment: Salting is to prevent creating a "rainbow" table, essentially a pre-computed list of all the hashed passwords.

Comment: And if two people have the same password, they won't have the same hashed password because the salts will be different.

Comment: Ok yeah, I'm definitely understanding that better now. Seriously appreciate it. I am going to go work on setting this up properly.

Comment: Also would not suggest to reengineer a solution which already exists... more practical and secure approach is to use some Identify Service ...